# How to organize images while publishing in Matlab?

Tags: html, matlab, plot

When I run some script from inside [publish() function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html), it gathers all data and drawn images into single generated HTML file.

Unfortunately, all images are gathered into one single wrapping array.

Is it possible to insert them into table or insert forced wraps between?

Adding something like

```
fprintf('<br/>');
```

between calling plot functions didn't help.